# webpack react ingress-nginx kubernetes shows Bad Gateway

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, microservices, nginx-ingress

All the deployments are running, all the pods are healthy. ingress-nginx is running. when I run `kubectl get ing`:

```
NAME          CLASS    HOSTS       ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
ingress-srv   <none>   myapp.com   192.168.49.2   80      13m
```

I set the hosts file for ingress.

this is the ingress-srv.yml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: nginx-ingress-default-backend
      port:
        number: 80

  rules:
    - host: myapp.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /posts
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: query-srv
                port:
                  number: 4002
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Exact // I tried "Prefix"
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

the issue ingress api is not routing correctly. and react app is set up with webpack-dev-server.  it's port is set to 8080. this is client-depl.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: kali/client
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  ports:
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

webpack config for client:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: ["regenerator-runtime/runtime", "./index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "main-bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ }],
  },
  devtool: "eval-cheap-source-map",
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    overlay: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: can you show the output of curl when accessing the react app externally?

Comment: @Thomas I get same error in terminal "<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
"

Comment: How is the reactjs app image built, how is the webserver launched?

Comment: @Yilmaz I tried your config with different image and it works fine. Can you please test this with 'mendhak/http-https-echo' image?

Answer (score 2):

First a word a caution: The webpack dev server is not intended to be used to serve the react app in production. You might want to investigate an alternative like nginx.

You get an error of `BadGateway` from your ingress. That means that the ingress recognizes the configuration, but can not reach the real service. Usually this is caused by a problem of the port mapping, but since you stated that you run the dev server with port 8080 and configured that in the kubernetes services as well, it should be fine.

I noticed that your deployment does not declare the port, this should be fixed:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: kali/client
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
```

But there is one more thing to consider when listening for connections beside the port: The network interface to use. The webpack dev server is preconfigured to listen only on the loopback (localhost) interface and to not be available externally. It is a dev server after all.

This can be changed using a different listen address, either in the webpack configuration or on the command line:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  }
};
```

CLI: `webpack serve --host 0.0.0.0`

Comment: when I add "host" property, I get "invalid host header" on the screen instead of Bad Gateway warning. and adding "ports:
          - containerPort: 8080" did not solve neither. I will share the webpack config

Comment: That is a good sign that shows that basic connectivity is possible. The allowed hostnames can/must be configured as well, see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts

Comment: @Thomas you are wrong with the part that containerPort has to be mentioned in the deployment. This is purely information and it does not open any port.

Comment: That is the difference between "should be fixed" and "must be fixed".

Comment: @Thomas i did with "webpack serve --host 0.0.0.0" it gave me "invalid host header" error. If i discard "--host 0.0.0.0" i get 502 BadGateway error again

Comment: you need the --host 0.0.0.0 so it listens on all interfaces, you need to additionally whitelist the hostname used to access it as linked in my other comment. To iterate again: Consider using a real webserver to serve your app, it saves you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `pathType: Exact` in your ingress definiton and exact expects that exact path like `https://<url>//?(.*) .` You need to change it to  `pathType: Prefix` ıf you are willing to use prefix `/?(.*)` to match and route with urls such as `http://<url>/<sample>`

Also you can check path types in official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types)

Comment: I tried "Prefix" too. I should have mentioned it

Comment: what is your main aim with that configuration?  If the request does not match with  path: /posts it should go to service client-srv ?

Comment: do you want to url rewrite or you want to transmit request with what exaclty it came ? such as /some/url > /some/url or /some/url >  /some ?  Also did you check that if you request towards to service and pods is it working as you expect ?

Comment: Kagan, since the client-srv is the last one, if request url does not match the above url's. it will hit the client-srv. I tried Prefix but it did not work. All pods are running. I created a node port service to send POST request to "posts" service and it did work.